# Can I store a non-text property in a DOM node in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, setattribute, getattribute

I would like to store an object in Javascript in a custom attribute of a DOM node.  I've tried setAttribute/getAttribute, but they convert the attribute into text.

Assume I've already done

```
node = document.getElementById( 'SAMPLE' );
object = { test: function( ){ stuff; } };
```

This doesn't work anywhere I've tested

```
node.setAttribute( 'info', object );
val = node.getAttribute( 'info' ) ;
```

because it leaves val with a string value.

If I do

```
node[ 'info' ] = object;
```

then

```
val = node[ 'info' ];
```

gives me back my object later in my script.

Will this work in pre-HTML5 browsers like old IEs? Is it safe?

Comment: You can "attach" it as a property, but generally you should leave host objects alone and only play with them via their published APIs.

Comment: Only one question.. WHY?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it as long as you use a sensible collision-proof name, especially if you're only storing primitive data. If you're storing objects, especially ones that hold functions, you can create a circular reference that can be difficult for old IE to detect, thereby causing a memory leak.

Comment: I'm trying to make the program global-free. Maybe not the best idea?  That's a good warning about the memory leak.  I'll look into that issue in more depth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can "attach" it as a property, but that's not a good idea. – RobG

So, here's my suggestion for an alternative:

1. Generate a unique string - easy way might be `Date.now().toString()` unless you're generating them in a loop or something. Use whatever works best here.
2. Have a global object, say `domdata = {};`
3. Assign `domdata[unique_string] = your_data_here;`
4. Save `node.setAttribute("data-dom-id",unique_string);`

You can now retrieve the data with:

5. Get `unique_string = node.getAttribute("data-dom-id");`
6. Retrieve `domdata[unique_string]`

Done! :)

Comment: Innovative solution. Though a sequential number might be a safer unique string.